# Input is hidden under keyboard when focused (Phonegap android)

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am using following code in my config.xml

```
<preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
```

but what it resulted is not acceptable as when i  focused on an input (input is  lying the bottom of the form) the input field is hidden by the keyboard

But as soon as i typed a character then form is scrolled to top automatically and this field is displayed properly. **It works fine on keypress, but I need this to do on focus**

I am trying to keep the input displayed even when focused before typing any thing. I tried to simulate the keypress like

```
$(".form-control").click(function (evt){
            var e = $.Event('keyup');
            e.which = 65;
            $(this).trigger(e);//it doesn't work
            $(this).val("");
       });
```

But nothing is working for me yet.

Comment: did u try with the jquery focus event? https://api.jquery.com/focus/

Comment: yes i tried focused but isn't work in  android .

Answer (score 0):

You should get the position of the input element using:
`$(this).offset().top;`

Then on the focus event listener scroll to the input position:

```
$('#input_id').on('focus', function() {
    document.body.scrollTop = $(this).offset().top;
});
```

You might want to trigger on focus for all of the form inputs:

```
$('#form_id').delegate(':input', 'focus', function() {
    document.body.scrollTop = $(this).offset().top;
})
```